# set VBox width to width of smaller of children in javafx

Tags: javafx, vbox

I'm trying to figure out how to get a VBox to make the preferred width be the smaller of the children's width?  Actually, I want the second child to be the determining factor in setting the width and the first child will then be sized to fit the VBox since it can wrap the text inside.

For example, I have this VBox containing two HBox children, each of which has a label inside it.

**VBox sizing to all children**

[image]

But what I want is for the VBox to size itself by the smaller child:

**VBox sized to smaller child**

[image]

The VBox is going to be setting the scene for a dialog box and my routines are going to be given that second box by someone else through a function, and I want that second box to set the width of the box and not the first one as the first one will probably be really long.

I don't want to use fixed numbers to set the width which is why I'm getting this problem.

Can I do this with just the parameters in XML or am I going to have to use some Java code calls to bind things together?

I've been playing with this in SceneBuilder without success.  The fxml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="0.0" spacing="2.0" style="-fx-border-color: yellow;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox id="box1" style="-fx-border-color: blue;">
         <children>
            <Label text="Text label one is really long" wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox id="box2" style="-fx-border-color: red;">
         <children>
            <Label text="Text label two" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind the preferred width of `box1` to the actual width of `box2`. You can do this in FXML (probably not in Scene Builder though), but note that you need to give `box2` an `fx:id` (not an `id`) to make it work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="0.0" spacing="2.0" style="-fx-border-color: yellow;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox id="box1" style="-fx-border-color: blue;" prefWidth="${box2.width}" >
         <children>
            <Label text="Text label one is really long" wrapText="true" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox fx:id="box2" style="-fx-border-color: red;">
         <children>
            <Label text="Text label two" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you James_D, that's a perfect solution!